# Extract date from date-and-time in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to use the system date to name my output files, I have created a variable to do that but I find it to be "unclean". How can I create a reporter procedure to create a variable that is just the current system date, say 18Feb2016, without removing items individually. Currently I am using

```
globals [
  time
  filename
]

to setup
  ca
  set time (remove-item 6(remove-item 7(remove-item 8 (remove "-"(remove " "(remove "." 
            (remove ":" date-and-time)))))))
  set filename (word "test-" time ".csv"
  if file-exists? filename
     [file-close
      file-delete filename
     ]
     file-open filename

end
```

Answer (score 3):

You could definitely reduce your code by using the `substring` primitive.

```
set date (remove "-" (substring date-and-time 16 27))
set time (remove "." remove ":" remove " " (substring date-and-time 0 15))
```

However, I don`t know if there is a more elegant way to access the system date and time in NetLogo without the need of string reconstruction.

Comment: There's also Colin Sheppard's time extension, https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/